# Как получить данные игрового сервера

Tags: php, ip, port

Получаю скриптом данные сервера (слоты, онлайн). Игра minecraft pe. При получении скрипт ничего не возвращает:

```
<?php
$lol = getserver("krossava.tk","15110");
echo $lol;
function getserver($ip,$port){
    $socket = fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,0.5);
    fwrite($socket,"\xfe");
    $data = fread($socket,256);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Но при получении сервера minecraft pc все данные присутствуют. Помогите разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что у разных игр одинаковые протоколы? Ищите документацию по MPE, ну или берите Wireshark и изучайте :)

Answer (score 0):

Проверить изначальное соединение можно следующим способом, в вашем случае - так:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$connected = socket_connect($socket, 'krossava.tk', 15110);
```

И в вашем случае его нет, поэтому функция ничего и не возвращает.

P.S. Извиняюсь за изначальный комментарий, относительно интерпретатора ошибся.